# On the non-injectivity of forgetful functors on Ob

Tags: category-theory

My [book](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/) asserts that, for several common categories, such **Vec**, **Grp**, **Top**, etc., the forgetful functor is not injective on the category's class of objects, $\mathcal{Ob}$.

> I'm looking for examples of this assertion for the forgetful $U_\mathbf{Vec} = U$ on **Vec**.

(By **Vec** I mean the category of vector spaces over **R**, with the **R**-linear transformations as morphisms.)

And a second, related question:

> Is there a $X\in \mathcal{Ob}_\mathbf{Set}$ such that
>
> 1. $|X| > 1$, and
>
>    $U(V\;) = X$ for *exactly one* $V\, \in \mathcal{Ob}_\mathbf{Vec}\;\;$?

P.S. One reason for my difficulties with this question is that the common modern mathematical practice of declaring superficially different entities as "essentially the same" (as in "a vector space $V$ and its double dual $V^{**}$ *are essentially the same*", or "all singletons *are essentially the same*") makes it difficult for me to settle questions regarding injectivity, which hinge crucially on knowing when two things are different (e.g. $V, W \in \mathcal{Ob}_\mathbf{Vec}$, on the one hand, and $U(V\;), U(W\;)\in\mathcal{Ob}_\mathbf{Set}$ on the other).

Edit: added a link to the book I referenced, and changed **Vect** to **Vec** to match the book's notation.

Comment: Dear kjo: Do you agree that $\mathbb R$ can be equipped with different $\mathbb R$-vector space structures?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: Yes, I see this now.  Thanks!

Comment: offtopic: What are those “\;” in your $\TeX$ code for?

Comment: @beroal: they are primarily tokens of my obsessive character; as a bonus, they insert a modicum of horizontal whitespace :)  Question to you: what prompted you to look at the $\LaTeX$ source?

Comment: @kjo: I read stackexchange questions in Liferea (a feed reader). It does not run JavaScript, so I see the source of formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $\bf{Vect}$ you can take one set and define different vector space structures on them. For example define a new addition $\oplus$ on the set $\mathbb{R}^2$ by setting $(a,b) \oplus (c,d) := (a + b + c+ d, b + d)$.
Together with the usual scalar multiplication
you get a vector space with a different vector space structure than the normal one on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Applying the forgetful functor gives you the same set.

In general you can take any 
bijection $\psi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and define 
$a \oplus b := \psi^{-1}(\psi(a) + \psi(b))$ and $a \otimes b := \psi^{-1}(\psi(a) \cdot \psi(b))$. This defines a new field structure on $\mathbb{R}$
with different units, inverse elements etc. But it will be still be a 
$\mathbb{R}$-vector (here $\mathbb{R}$ considered with its usal structure) space by using the above multplication for scalar multiplication, too.
Generalizing this gives you a negative answer to your second question.

The general idea is that you look at a set without the "meaning" its elements have in the concrete category. You are right when you say that $V$ and $V^{**}$
are *essentially the same* because we have a (canonical) isomorphism
in the case that $V$ is finite dimensional. One point of category theory is to make this difference between *being equal* and *being essentially the same* (meaning isomorphic) more visible.

Comment: Thanks!  I gather that $U(V\;) \neq U(V^{**})$?

Comment: You are right. They may be isomorphic, but $V^{**}$ contains linaer maps $V^* \rightarrow k$ and these are not elements of $V$.